Understanding the Data Flow in CREW AI and Clarifying Some Doubts
Context
I'm developing a research agent using crew-ai that generates papers from prompts.
Issue
I'm unsure whether to pass the user's question through tasks or agents. Here's the relevant code:
class Tasks:
    def task_question(self, agent):
        return Task(
            description="Generate a research paper outline",
            agent=agent,
            expected_output="A structured document with 5 chapters, including character descriptions and main plot points per chapter"
        )

class Agents:
    def __init__(self):
        self.llm = LLM(
            model=os.getenv("MODEL_NAME"),
            api_key=os.environ.get("GROQ_API_KEY")
        )
    
    def questioning_agent(self):
        return Agent(
            llm=self.llm,
            role='Questioner',
            goal="Ask up to 3 counter-questions based on user's previous answers",
            backstory="You are a researcher who analyzes and challenges assumptions",
            allow_delegation=False,
            verbose=False
        )

Question

Where should i pass it?
What's the data flow in the multi agent system of crew ai ?

